# how to pass ajax response value to another page?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to send an AJAX response to a PHP file. Based on the response I would like to redirect to another page. If the response is `success` I would like to redirect to a 'thank you' page along with the parameter data.

How can I pass this transactionId to another page?

```
if ($result->success) 
{
    print_r("success!: " .$result->transaction->id);
} 
else if ($result->transaction) {
    print_r("Error processing transaction:");
    print_r("\n  code: " .$result->transaction->processorResponseCode);
    print_r("\n  text: " .$result->transaction->processorResponseText);
}
else 
{
    print_r("Validation errors: \n");
    print_r($result->errors->deepAll());
}
```

```js
$('#paymentForm').submit(function() {
    var serializedData = $(this).serialize();
    $.post('card.php', serializedData, function(response) {
        // Log the response to the console
        console.log("Response: "+response);
        alert(response);

        if (response == "success") {
            window.location.href = 'http://www.google.com';
        }
    });
});
});
```

Comment: `window.location.href = 'http://www.google.com?id='+id+'';` something like that

Comment: i'm getting only alert.I would like to redirect  to another page.how to pass?

Comment: what is the output of  `console.log("Response: "+response);`?

Comment: It's easier if `card.php` returns json, since you want to check for status and get the ID. Then your response variable in the ajax callback will be a proper object, instead of just plain text (which you need to parse manually to get the ID).

Comment: Response: success!: q3a2xptv

Answer (score 3, accepted):

change your php output from

```
if ($result->success) 
{
    print_r("success!: " .$result->transaction->id);
} 
else if ($result->transaction) {
    print_r("Error processing transaction:");
    print_r("\n  code: " .$result->transaction->processorResponseCode);
    print_r("\n  text: " .$result->transaction->processorResponseText);
}
else 
{
    print_r("Validation errors: \n");
    print_r($result->errors->deepAll());
}
```

to

```
if ($result->success) 
{
    echo json_encode(array('status'=>'success','id'=>$result->transaction->id));
} 
else if ($result->transaction) {
    echo json_encode(array('status'=>'error','code'=>$result->transaction->processorResponseCode, 'text'=> $result->transaction->processorResponseText)));
}
else 
{
   echo   json_encode(array('status'=>'error','text'=>$result->errors->deepAll()));

}
```

and change your js to the following

```
$('#paymentForm').submit(function() {
    var serializedData = $(this).serialize();
    $.post('card.php', serializedData, function(response) {
        // Log the response to the console
        console.log("Response: "+response);
        alert(response);
        var data= $.parseJSON(response);
        if (data.status == "success") {
            window.location.replace('http://www.google.com?id='+data.id)‌​;
        }else{
            alert('Operation Failed');
            if(data.code){
                console.log('response code: '+data.code);
            }
            console.log('response text: '+data.text);
        }
    });
});
});
```

Comment: Accurate,but add other two conditions also in `ajax` response (means to say if error happen). Please add that too. +1

Comment: i have edited my answer to add the else condition in ajax as you requested. so if request fails, it will show an alert of operation failed message, and your response text and code will be printed in console.

Comment: @creative : try, `window.location.replace('http://www.google.com?id='+data.id);` instead of  `window.location.href = 'http://www.google.com?id='+data.id;`

Comment: you are welcome. also updated this change in my answer for future reference.

Comment: @AshrafulIslamTushar its works in chrome only.other browsers not supported this js.plz help

Comment: are you getting any error in browser console ? whats not working ? redirection ? or ajax output !

Comment: try in firefox, u should see the ajax request in browser console. see the response of the ajax request in console. this response is not browser dependent. u should get the response in all browser.

Comment: sorry i didn't get any message in console.

Comment: can you give any link of your page ? its hard to find out the problem like this.

Answer (score 1):

looking at your php code - it never returns `success`, it will return `success!: somthing` so this condition `if (response == "success")` is never true

you could use

```
if(response.indexOf("success") == 0)
```

or change the response in the php file

Comment: yes i changed response and its not redirecting.it still in the same page

Comment: what does the console say after `console.log("Response: "+response);` ? it is possible you need to trim the string, or go for "broke" and change the condition to `if(response.indexOf("success") > -1)`

Answer (score 1):

You can send the response variables you'd like by incorporating them into a query on the redirect.

For instance if you wanted to pass on `foo` to your redirected php `domain.com/bar.php`:

```
var url = 'domain.com/bar.php?foo=' + foo
window.location.href = url;
```

And then on the PHP page, you can use this data:

```
$bits = parse_url($url);
parse_str($bits['query'], $query);
echo $query['foo']
```